# How can I make a command putting an effect on all players at a certain object?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a command where whenever a player stands at/in an object like a Cobweb, they will get a Wither effect. I can't seem to get my own one to work.

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far? You may be on the right track and only need a small change

Answer (score 2):

Put the following into an repeating command block:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:web 0 effect @a[c=1] minecraft:wither DURATION_OF_EFFECT LEVEL_OF_WITHER_EFFECT
```

for example

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ minecraft:web 0 effect @a[c=1] minecraft:wither 1 1
```

This will give everyone standing in an cobweb the wither effect

[image]

Comment: Do **not** mix `@a` as the executor with `@p` as the nested selector. `@a` is the only selector capable of targeting dead players. If a players dies inside cobweb, they will still be running the `/effect` command but will instead target the nearest-living player instead of themselves. This could have drastic consequences and potentially break a map if a player doesn't respawn. Use the same selector (such as executor of `@a` with nested `@a[c=1]`, or executor of `@e[type=Player]` with nested `@p`).

Comment: Oh, didn't now that @a can target dead player , fixed it